# How to change the place of Descriptive Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, smartdiagram

In the diagram below, I want to change the place of the rectangle and the circle with each other. I want the rectangle be placed on the left and the circle on the right. How can I do it?

One more thing, is there a way to change the circle to a rectangle or an oval?
[image]

```
\smartdiagramset{description title text width=2.5cm,
    description text width=8cm,description width=10cm}
\smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{
    {$ Step ~1 $,abcdefghigklmno pqrst uvwxyz}% <==============
}
```

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: (Although it looks like you're using the 2 corresponding packages.)

Answer (score 5):

I use plain TikZ, with some `style`s of the above answer of @Ignasi, without using the `matrix` library.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{
basic/.style={rounded corners,draw=gray,drop shadow,align=center,font=\sffamily},
filling/.style={top color=white,bottom color=#1!80},
description/.style={basic,text width=5cm},
title/.style={basic,ellipse,text width=2cm},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[nodes={filling=teal}]
(0,0) node[description] (A) {It is defined as a long piece of timber or metal}
(A.east) node[right,title]{Beam}
;
\path[nodes={filling=magenta}]
(0,-1.2) node[description] (B) {It is a plant having yellow flowers}
(B.east) node[right,title]{Daffodil}
;
\path[nodes={filling=orange}]
(0,-2.4) node[description] (C) {It is defined as a system \dots}
(C.east) node[right,title]{Galaxy}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is exactly what I want

Answer (score 3):

I think that you will have to change `smartdiagram` code to change the position of descriptions and text. As i don't know how to do it, here you have a possible alternative with a `matrix`. There are probably better ways for changing row colors, but I don't know them. I'm open to alternatives.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shadows, shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{
basic/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, draw=gray,  drop shadow, 
    align=center, anchor=center, font=\sffamily},
filling/.style={top color=#1!10, bottom color=#1!80},
title/.style={basic, ellipse, text width=2cm},
description/.style={basic, text width=5cm}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes, column sep=1pt, row sep=3mm, 
    column 1/.style={nodes={description}},
    column 2/.style={nodes={title}},
    row 1/.style={nodes={filling=blue}},
    row 2/.style={nodes={filling=red}},
    row 3/.style={nodes={filling=green}},
    ]{
    It is defined as a long piece of timber or metal & Beam\\
    It is a plant having yellow flowers & Daffodil\\
    It is defined as a system \dots & Galaxy\\};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `title` and `description` are styles without parameters

Comment: @BlackMild You are right. From a previous version code. I've corrected it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can change the arrangement of the nodes by editing the styles quite easily:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\tikzset{
   description title/.append style={
      anchor=west
   },
   description/.append style={
      anchor=east
   }
}

\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{description title text width=2.5cm,
    description text width=8cm,description width=10cm}
\smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]{
    {$ Step ~1 $,abcdefghigklmno pqrst uvwxyz}% <==============
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The only flaw with this approach is that the shadow of the description box covers the node with the step, which is due to the fact that the nodes are still drawn in the same order as before.

If you want to change this behavior, you need to define your own diagram based on the code the package provides. Sasly, the package provides no easy way to add custom styles and it is not feasable to patch the relevant internal commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\tikzset{
   description title/.append style={
      anchor=west
   },
   description/.append style={
      anchor=east
   }
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\smartRevDescriptiveDiagram}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
        \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#1}{%
            \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}
            %%% reverse the order of the subitems:
            \let\revsitem\empty
            \foreach\currentsmitem in \smitem {
                \ifx\revsitem\empty
                    \xdef\revsitem{\currentsmitem}%
                \else
                    \xdef\revsitem{\currentsmitem,\revsitem}%
                \fi
            }
            %%%
            \foreach \subitem [count=\xii] in \revsitem{%
            \ifnumequal{\xii}{1}{% true
                \node[description,drop shadow]
                (module\xi) at (0,0-\xi*\sm@core@descriptiveitemsysep) {\subitem};
            }{}
            \ifnumequal{\xii}{2}{% true
                \node[description title,drop shadow]
                (module-title\xi) at (0,0-\xi*\sm@core@descriptiveitemsysep) {\subitem};
                }{}
            }%
        }%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{description title text width=2.5cm,
    description text width=8cm,description width=10cm}
\smartRevDescriptiveDiagram{
    {$ Step ~1 $,abcdefghigklmno pqrst uvwxyz}% <==============
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Finally, as shown in the other answers already, using Ti*k*Z's `shapes.geometric` library, you can change the shape of the circle to an ellipse:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{
   description title/.append style={
      anchor=west,
      ellipse,
      inner ysep=10pt
   },
   description/.append style={
      anchor=east,
   }
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\smartRevDescriptiveDiagram}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center, let hypenation}]
        \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#1}{%
            \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}
            %%% reverse the order of the subitems:
            \let\revsitem\empty
            \foreach\currentsmitem in \smitem {
                \ifx\revsitem\empty
                    \xdef\revsitem{\currentsmitem}%
                \else
                    \xdef\revsitem{\currentsmitem,\revsitem}%
                \fi
            }
            %%%
            \foreach \subitem [count=\xii] in \revsitem{%
            \ifnumequal{\xii}{1}{% true
                \node[description, drop shadow]
                (module\xi) at (0,0-\xi*\sm@core@descriptiveitemsysep) {\subitem};
            }{}
            \ifnumequal{\xii}{2}{% true
                \node[description title, drop shadow]
                (module-title\xi) at (0,0-\xi*\sm@core@descriptiveitemsysep) {\subitem};
                }{}
            }%
        }%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{
    description title text width=2.5cm,
    description text width=8cm, 
    description width=10cm
}
\smartRevDescriptiveDiagram{
    {$ Step ~1 $,abcdefghigklmno pqrst uvwxyz}% <==============
}

\end{document}
```

[image]